# REGEX: Match <.. class='row'..> to use in js .split()

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to match every element that has an attribute 'class'='row' in order to use it as separator in javascript .split() method. How can I archive this with regular expressions? In the following string `<div class="row" tabindex="0">` should be matched.

```
<div class="row" tabindex="0"><div class="cell">rect</div><div class="cell">A</div><div class="cell">0</div><div class="cell">0</div><div class="cell">10</div><div class="cell">10</div></div><div class="row" tabindex="0"><div class="cell">rect</div></div>
```

Comment: Why are you matching HTML with a regular expression?

Comment: It's better to parse the html

Comment: Every time you want to use Regex for parsing HTML consider using actual DOM methods or something like Cheerio. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp  https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio

Comment: Take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: Read [TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/128165)

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery and save yourself the headache.

```
let html = $(`  <div class="row" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="cell">rect</div>
                    <div class="cell">A</div>
                    <div class="cell">0</div>
                    <div class="cell">0</div>
                    <div class="cell">10</div>
                    <div class="cell">10</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" tabindex="0">
                    <div class="cell">rect</div>
                </div>`);

let rows = html.filter('.row');
```

Then if you need the raw HTML string of a specific row:

```
let row1HTML = rows[0].innerHTML;
```